# JSON is being received in android, but it won't parse. What is my issue?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, getjson

As title suggests, here is the format of the JSON:
http://prntscr.com/elb4fz. Now I'm not sure if I have the parse method working properly as I think that SearchResults is the array and it'll show each individual result as an object.

I have my networkutils code as such:

```
package companionsdirect.practice;


import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by Albedo on 3/17/2017.
 */

public class NetworkingUtil {

    private static final String TAG = "NetworkUtils";
    List<Product> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlSpec);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

            if(connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new IOException(connection.getResponseMessage() +
                ": with " + urlSpec);
            }

            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            out.close();
            return out.toByteArray();

        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public String getUrlString(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
        return new String(getUrlBytes(urlSpec));
    }

    public List<Product> fetchItems(String url) {
        try {
            String jsonString = getUrlString(url);
            Log.i(TAG, "Received JSON: " + jsonString);
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            parseItems(items, jsonBody);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to fetch items", ioe);
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON", je);
        }
        return items;
    }

    public List<Product> getProdList() {
        return items;
    }

    private void parseItems(List<Product> items, JSONObject jsonBody) throws IOException, JSONException {
        //JSONObject reviewItem = jsonBody.getJSONObject();
        JSONArray reviewArray = jsonBody.getJSONArray("SearchResults");

        for(int i = 0;i<reviewArray.length();i++) {
            JSONObject reviewItem = reviewArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Product currentProductReview = new Product();
            currentProductReview.setmSummary(reviewItem.getString("Summary"));
            currentProductReview.setmTitle(reviewItem.getString("Title"));
            currentProductReview.setmRecordType(reviewItem.getString("RecordType"));

            items.add(currentProductReview);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the activity with the asynctask:

```
package companionsdirect.practice;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReturnReviewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String builtURL;
    List<Product> prodList;

    private static final String TAG = "ReturnReviewsActivity";
    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_return_reviews);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MSG);

        prodList = new ArrayList<Product>();
        builtURL = url;
        new FetchItemsTask().execute();

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        for(Product x : prodList) {
            tv.setText(x.getmTitle() + " " + x.getRating() + " \n");
        }


    }

    private class FetchItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  {
        private List<Product> list;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            NetworkingUtil productData = new NetworkingUtil();
            list = productData.fetchItems(builtURL);

            return null;
        }


    }



}
```

What gives? The log shows that the json is being received,but I try to set the textview to whatever is in the list and nothing shows.

Comment: Can you share the JSON?

Comment: It was included as a screenshot in my first few sentences. Should I post it instead? I didn't want to make the original post so long

Comment: Apologies, I completely skimmed over it. Taking a look now.

Comment: `AsyncTask`s are _asynchronous_. That task isn't going to be done when your `for` loop runs to set the texts.

Comment: Yep. You probably also want `tv.append(...)`, rather than `tv.setText(...)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    for(Product x : prodList) {
        //append the text view
        tv.append(x.getmTitle() + " "  + x.getRating() + " \n");
    }
```